# Not getting local notification in IOS neither on simulator nor on physical device

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, react-native-push-notification

Im using [React Native Push Notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

And Can't get local notifications to show on IOS. Not on device nor on simulator.

I have configured the native exactly as showed in the docs - [PushNotificationIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content) and [Manual linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking)

And implemented the same exact service from the repo example - [here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/tree/master/example)

Both the local and scheduled notifications trigger and `onNotification` callback is getting called, returning notification object, only no notification is seen on simulator nor device..

There is an issue opened issue from 2017 but with no solution.. [Not getting local notification in ios](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/478)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your steps for validating that you are not getting these notifications? Please do not that iOS only displays notifications when the app is not in the foreground. For apps in the foreground, you have to display a message in app.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I was not aware of that. once the app in foreground ground it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

So answering myself... apparently (as @Brian Gerhards stated in the comments)  on IOS you cant send notifications when the app is foreground (opened) so once I attempted to send a scheduled notification of 5 seconds and minimized the app it was sent perfectly. 
Not sure if I missed this info or its not stated in RN native docs.

Anyway hope this will help someone in the future